# Derivative of a periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $f(x) = f(1-x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. If $f$ is differentiable every where, then $f'(0) = -f'(1)$.

Why is it not the case that $f'(0) = f'(1)$ since by definition,
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}.
$$ But since $f(0) = f(1-1) = f(1)$ and $f(h) = f(1-h)$ we have
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(1-h)-f(1)}{h} = f'(1),
$$ since $f$ is everywhere differentiable and so the limit exists regardless of which side we take the limit from (i.e. $+h\, $ vs $-h$).

I see why $f'(0) = -f'(1)$ since
$$
-f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(1)-f(1-h)}{h} = f'(1).
$$ I would just like to know where my reasoning is incorrect. I thought since the function is differentiable we should be able to let $h$ vanish from any direction and reach a unique limit?

Comment: $f(1-h)-f(1)=-\Delta y$

Comment: Of course! I think I was confusing myself with considering letting $|h| \to 0$ rather than actually looking at the difference quotient.

Comment: This is not the def'n of a periodic function. Periodic means that f(x)=f(k+x) for all x for some fixed k.